# How to implement fill constructor and range constructor for sequence containers unambiguously

Tags: containers, c++03

Sequence containers need to have fill constructors and range constructors, i.e. these must both work, assuming `MyContainer` models a sequence container whose `value_type` is `int` and `size_type` is `std::size_t`:

```
// (1) Constructs a MyContainer containing the number '42' 4 times.
MyContainer<int> c = MyContainer<int>(4, 42);

// (2) Constructs a MyContainer containing the elements in the range (array.begin(), array.end())
std::array<int, 4> array = {1, 2, 3, 4};
MyContainer<int> c2 = MyContainer<int>(array.begin(), array.end());
```

Trouble is, I'm not sure how to implement these two constructors. These signatures don't work:

```
template<typename T>
MyContainer<T>::MyContainer(const MyContainer::size_type n, const MyContainer::value_type& val);

template<typename T>
template<typename OtherIterator>
MyContainer<T>::MyContainer(OtherIterator i, OtherIterator j);
```

In this case, an instantiation like in example 1 above selects the range constructor instead of fill constructor, since `4` is an int, not a `size_type`. It works if I pass in `4u`, but if I understand the requirements correctly, any positive integer should work.

If I template the fill constructor on the size type to allow other integers, the call is ambiguous when `value_type` is the same as the integer type used.

I had a look at the Visual C++ implementation for `std::vector` and they use some special magic to only enable the range constructor when the template argument is an iterator (`_Is_iterator<_Iter>`). I can't find any way of implementing this with standard C++.

So my question is... how do I make it work?

Note: I am not using a C++11 compiler, and boost is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've got the solution space right: Either disambiguate the call by passing in only explicitly `size_t`-typed `n`s, or use SFINAE to only apply the range constructor to actual iterators. I'll note, however, that there's nothing "magic" (that is, nothing based on implementation-specific extensions) about MSVC's `_Is_iterator`. The source is available, and it's basically just a static test that the type isn't an integral type. There's a whole lot of boilerplate code backing it up, but it's all standard C++.

A third option, of course, would be to add another fill constructor overload which takes a signed size.

Comment: You're right, `_Is_iterator` isn't magic; I just assumed it was since Intellisense wouldn't show me its definition, which is what usually happens with magic functions :) After implementing `enable_if`, `remove_const`, `remove_volatile`, `remove_cv`, `integral_constant`, `true_type`, `false_type` and `is_integral` (all of which thankfully don't need magic), implementing a `is_iterator` becomes just `template<class T> is_iterator : public integral_constant<bool, !is_integral<T>::value> {};`. Thanks!